# css and html code isn't working properly in safari, what should I do?

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, vendor-prefix

some of my html and css code isn't working in safari. I read about vendor prefixes and webkits but didn't understand much. is there any article or video by which I'm gonna understand what to do? (p.s I'm beginner, just started css and html)

I made several radio button which changes color on hover and click, but it doesn't work in safari and does in google chrome.

Comment: Safari's notoriously difficult to style some controls. https://bryntum.com/blog/3-ways-to-style-radio-buttons-with-modern-css/ may help (there's a Safari-friendly and non-Safari friendly technique in there), but folks who have very particular design needs for their radio buttons tend to create a custom element that uses JS.

Comment: If you show us the code that works in Chrome and describe what isn’t working in Safari you stand a much better chance of us being able to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try putting `-webkit-appearance: none;` in your css.

Comment: Thank you so much everybody! I added -webkit-appearance: none; and it worked!